# How to compute a cubic root of a complex number in C?

Tags: c

As the name suggested, I'd like to compute cubic roots of a complex number in C. ***cbrt*** doesn't work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <cmath.h>

int main(){
    double complex x, z = 1+2*I;
    x = cbrt(z);
    printf("z is %f + %fi \n", creal(z), cimag(z));
    printf("x is %f + %fi \n", creal(x), cimag(x));
    return(0);
}
```

The output is as follows.

```
z is 1.000000 + 2.000000i 
x is 1.000000 + 0.000000i
```

Comment: Note there are always 3 cubic roots for a complex number. Which one do you pick?

Comment: Are you sure `cbrt()` operates on complex numbers? The standard library function in `math.h` takes a `double` argument and returns a `double` value. Instead, try `x = cpow(z, 1.0/3+0*I);`. That should at least give you *one* of the complex roots.

Comment: What is `cmath.h`? It's not standard. You missed the generic math header, otoh. NEvertheless, what about the doucmentation of `cbrt` is unclear? What does "doesn't work" mean? Your compiler should warn at least, don't ignore warnings - fix them before asking.

Comment: @Olaf I used Mac Terminal. No warnings appear. Actually it took me a while to figure out it's the cubic root. I know it looks clear from this example, but not so when being part of a large computation.

Comment: @Bathsheba Actually it doesn't matter for my case. It is a middle step in my computation code. The other two roots will be compensated in the final step. As long as it's a non-zero cubic root, it's fine.

Comment: Nothiong of your response makes sense. In fact you don't reply to my comment. Read it again and try to understand what I wrote. It would make **a little** sense if you copy/pasted this code from somewhere without any underwstanding of it. In that case, I recommend to learn about the parts you use, most of them are easy to find. Only `cmath.h` is not clear, as pointed out by me and others, it's not standard and can change everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cbrt doesn't work.**

That function works on real values. [@squeamish ossifrage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51397996/how-to-compute-a-cubic-root-of-a-complex-number-in-c/51401542#comment89767596_51397996)
`x is 1.000000 + 0.000000i` is a reasonable result.

```
double cbrt(double x);
```

> The `cbrt` functions compute the real cube root of `x`.  C11dr §7.12.7.1 2

A good compiler with warnings fully enabled with report on the following.  **Save time**, enable all compiler warnings.

```
// warning expected such as:
// warning: conversion to 'long double' from 'complex double' discards imaginary component [-Wconversion]
x = cbrt(z);
```

---

**How to compute a cubic root of a complex number in C?**

`<cmath.h>` is not part of the C standard library.  Its role here is unclear.

Code can use `double complex cpow(double complex, double complex);`

```
x = cpow(z, 1.0/3.0);
...
// Ouptut
// x is 1.219617 + 0.471711i
```

I do not find a `double complex ccbrt(double complex);` in the standard library nor access to one via type-generic math `<tgmath.h>`.

---

**... to compute cubic roots ...**

Emphasis on plural "roots" here: to compute all 'n' roots:

```
  int n = 3;
  const double complex two_pi_i = 2.0 * asin(-1.0) * I;
  double complex rotate = cexp(two_pi_i / n);
  x = cpow(z, 1.0 / 3.0);
  for (int k = 0; k < n; k++) {
    printf("x[%d] is % f + % fi \n", k, creal(x), cimag(x));
    x *= rotate;
  }
```

Output

```
x[0] is  1.219617 +  0.471711i 
x[1] is  1.018322 + -0.820363i 
x[2] is -0.201294 + -1.292075i
```

Comment: IMO a complex root function would be problematic and against the standard's directions, because it had to return a compound type with the results. For this either a static variable had to be used (not thread-safe) or dynamic allocation which would make the function heavily depend on `malloc`.

Comment: @olaf Interesting thoughts.  The complex square root exist `csqrt()` exists so returning a `complex` has standard C library precedence without a static variable nor allocation.  `ccbrt()` would have an additional challenges to precisely specify which of the 3 roots to return.  I suspect its low need has not admitted `ccbrt()` to the [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Libc&redirect=no) club.

Comment: I would consider complex support in C has not really high priority. They have been made optional with C11 for a good reason. Problem with specifying which root to yield is you had to call it multiple times, causing more overhead. This is another problem for their intended usage with large scale arrays. Sure, one could pass an array to be filled, but that would also be uncommon. Finally, I'm not sure how often cubic roots of `_Complex` are really needed (I doubt in fact many C programs require standard complex at all - with decreasing importance for the future (NumPy, heavy optimised libs, …).

Answer (score 1):

I would look at this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1297186/cube-roots-of-complex-numbers) from the Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Essentially you want to compute the `radius` and `angle` of the Eurler formula. Then divide both the `radius` and `angle` by three (see link). So first you need to convert your complex number to Euler format. I don't have time now to figure that out, but maybe this gave you an idea at where to look.

Hope this helps!

---

**Addition:** @squeamish probably has a better idea with [cpow](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.bpxbd00/cpow.htm), but as he mentioned this will only return one of the roots.